# Problema con Laravel - Subir Imágenes a Hosting Compartido

Tags: laravel, imagen

Buen día, tengo un problema, aun soy principiante con Laravel, y por favor agradeceria si me pueden ayudar. La cosa es que quiero subir imágenes a la carpeta "imagenes" dentro del "public_html", en un hosting compartido pero me resulta el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He modificado los archivos "index.php", "AppServiceProvider.php" y "filesystems.php", para cambiar la ruta publica o eso era lo que estuve averiguando, pero no me funciona, este es el código.

**Index**

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel55/bootstrap/app.php';

$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__.'../public_html/';
});
```

**AppServiceProvider**

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path().'../public_html/';
        });
    }
```

**filesystems**

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            // Problema
            'root' => public_path('imagenes'),  
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],
```

**Controlador**

```
public function store(PostStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $post = Post::create($request->all());
        //Imagen
        if ($request->file('imagenPost')) {
            // Problema
            $path = Storage::disk('imagenes')->put('imagenes', $request->file('imagenPost'));
            $post->fill(['imagenPost' => asset($path)])->save();
        }
        //Etiquetas
        $post->etiquetas()->sync($request->get('etiquetas'));
        //Mensaje con sweet alert
        Alert::success('Post guardado con éxito');
        return redirect()->route('posts.index', $post->id);

    }
```

**Y el fragmento de mi formulario**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('imagenPost', 'Imagen Post')}}
    {{ Form::file('imagenPost')}}

</div>
```

Agradeceré mucho cualquier ayuda, gracias...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando modifiques archivos de configuración (como filesystems.php) e incluso algún archivo `.htaccess` trata de siempre correr el comando: `php artisan cache:clear` ó `php artisan config:cache` para limpiar el caché de Laravel